# Not able to set query param in $http GET call

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to give value from dropdown to $http get in angular to show record from it. but it won't show. here's my code btw.

.js

```
app.controller("cobacont", ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.cari = function() {
        $http.get('https://........a={{month}}').then(function(response) {
            ...........
        });
    };
}]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update this line for code correction

```
$http.get('https://........a='+$scope.month).then(function(response){
```

Comment: done, btw if i have more than one querry params like $http.get('https://........a=..b=..') should i do this .  $http.get('https://........a=..b=..'+$scope.month +scope.year ) ? thank you before

Comment: for more query param you need to do like `$http.get('https://........a='+$scope.month+'b='+scope.year )`

Comment: Thank you very much, this helping so much. thank you